# Flipping names of the two server machines

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

Following is my scenario.

I have maintained two servers machines.On one machine(lets call it machine-1) I have installed SharePoint Server 2013 which is using Active Directory Installed with users maintained in another server machine(lets call it machine-2).

On the Active Directory Machine I am having my Internet connection also.

Now I want to flip the two machines so that I could just swap the names of two machines that is machine-1 to machine-2 and machine-2 to machine-1.

I did that but problem is that now the users are not being able to connect to the SharePoint Server Sites?

**My Understanding**

I think the problem is that first I was accessing sites in SharePoint using "http://machine-1:87:/sites/mine" but Now since I have changed the name of underlying mchaine to machine-02 I need to to "http://machine-2:87:/sites/mine" Does that mean I need to change my sites name in SharePoint Server 2013?

Comment: Try asking on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try using IP addresses and verify the FQDN is not the issue.

Comment: changing machine names with servers like sharepoint and sql server in the backend is not impossible, but not necessarily an easy task.  there are lots of factors to consider.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the Alternate Access Mapping in SharePoint and make sure the DNS related settings are correct after the rename.  If you've made any changes directly in IIS - you need to look at those and make sure they match as well.

If your spending a lot of time trying to figure this out - I would recommend you backup the content databases, rebuild the server, then restore the content databases to your web applications. Unless you've heavily customized any of your service settings this should take a day or less for a single server.